# jQuery click handler always grabs the button in first available row of table, not the one that is actually clicked

Tags: jquery, onclick, display

I am using a jQuery library written by someone else (Bootstable.js). Since it only updates the html, I have to create my own Ajax function to send the info to a database, one of those items being an id number (which is the first column of every row). Every time I update the table, it is only grabbing the first row of those that are available (ID = 4). How can I access the correct button?

Here is my page:

```js
//Init the array
var array = [];

document.title = 'Public IPs';

$(function() {
  /*
  Init the dialogs
   */
  $('#table_edit_dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'fade',
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    close: function() {
      location.reload();
    }
  });
  $('#confirm_table_edit_dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'fade',
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    buttons: {
      "Confirm": function() {
        updateTable();
        $(this).dialog('close');
      },
      "Cancel": function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        location.reload();
        console.log('Clicked Cancel button');
      }
    }
  });
  //Initalize the table
  initTable();

  //Click handler for edit accept button
  $('#bAcep').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Clicked bAcep button');
    //Get the <td> elements that are not the first or last (id and button)
    let text = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('td:gt(0):lt(6)');
    //Get the id text in the first <td> element. To be used in the php script
    let id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('td:eq(0)').text();
    //For debugging
    console.log('ID of row: ' + id);
    //Push the ID to the array to send to php
    array.push(id);
    //Push the rest to the array
    text.each(function() {
      array.push($(this).text());
    });
    //Open the confirm dialog
    $('#confirm_table_edit_dialog').dialog('open');
  });
  //Reload the page on Cancel button click
  $('#bCanc').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Clicked bCanc button');
    location.reload();
  })
});

function initTable() {
  //Make the table editable
  $('#editable_table').SetEditable({
    //Don't allow editing of ID,IP Address, or Vendor column
    columnsEd: "3,4,5,6",
    onEdit: function(row) {
      console.log('Called onEdit');
      $('#bAcep').trigger('click');
    }
  });
  //Remove the delete button from each row
  //It will not be used. All deletions will be handled via database.
  $('td').each(function() {
    $('#bElim').remove();
  });
  //Add noShowButton class to every row greater than the first and less than the 3rd
  //These will always be static entries
  $('tr:gt(0):lt(3)').addClass('noShowButton');
  //Remove the edit button
  $('.noShowButton').find('.btn').remove();
}

function updateTable() {
  console.log('Called updateTable function');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'includes/edit_IP_table.php',
    data: {
      array: array
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      //Show all the updated info in a dialog
      let valid_ip = '<h3>Updated IP Table:</h3>' +
        '<p><strong>Row ID: </strong>' + data.id + '</p>' +
        '<p><strong>IP: </strong>' + data.ip + '</p>' +
        '<p><strong>Vendor: </strong>' + data.vendor + '</p>' +
        '<p><strong>Assigned To: </strong>' + data.assigned_to + '</p>' +
        '<p><strong>Policy: </strong>' + data.policy + '</p>' +
        '<p><strong>DNS: </strong>' + data.dns + '</p>' +
        '<p><strong>Other Info: </strong>' + data.other_info + '</p>';
      $('#table_edit_dialog').html(valid_ip);
      $('#table_edit_dialog').dialog('open');
      //Clear out the array
      array = [];
      console.log('Emptied array: ' + array);

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
      array = [];
      console.log('Emptied array: ' + array);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table id="editable_table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>IP Address</th>
      <th>Vendor</th>
      <th>Assigned To</th>
      <th>Firewall Policies</th>
      <th>DNS Records</th>
      <th>Other Info</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th name="buttons"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1" class="noShowButton">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>123.456.789.10</td>
      <td>AT&amp;T</td>
      <td>router</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td name="buttons">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2" class="noShowButton">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>123.456.789.10</td>
      <td>AT&amp;T</td>
      <td>some web site</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td name="buttons">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3" class="noShowButton">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>123.456.789.10</td>
      <td>AT&amp;T</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td name="buttons">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="4">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>123.456.789.102</td>
      <td>AT&amp;T</td>
      <td>asdfasdfdsaf</td>
      <td>asdfsdfadsf</td>
      <td>some DNS stuff</td>
      <td>hello!!</td>
      <td name="buttons">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right"><button id="bEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="rowEdit(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </span></button><button id="bAcep" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display:none;" onclick="rowAcep(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></button>
          <button
            id="bCanc" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display:none;" onclick="rowCancel(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> </span></button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="5">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>123.456.789.10</td>
      <td>AT&amp;T</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td name="buttons">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right"><button id="bEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="rowEdit(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </span></button><button id="bAcep" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display:none;" onclick="rowAcep(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></button>
          <button
            id="bCanc" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display:none;" onclick="rowCancel(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> </span></button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="">
      <td>6</td>
      <td>123.456.789.10</td>
      <td>AT&amp;T</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>asdfasdfasdf</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td name="buttons">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right"><button id="bEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="rowEdit(this);" style=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> </span></button><button id="bAcep" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default accept" style="display: none;"
            onclick="rowAcep(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> </span></button><button id="bCanc" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display: none;" onclick="rowCancel(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> </span></button></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the library. I've left out the `rowElim()`, `rowAddNew()`, and `TableToCSV()` functions since I will not be using them. I have also translated the comments to English, since they were all written in Spanish to help understanding them.

```
/*
Bootstable
 @description  Javascript library to make HMTL tables editable, using Bootstrap
 @version 1.1
 @autor Tito Hinostroza
*/
"use strict";
//Global variables
var params = null;          //Parameters
var colsEdi =null;
var newColHtml = '<div class="btn-group pull-right">'+
    '<button id="bEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="rowEdit(this);">' +
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" > </span>'+
    '</button>'+
    '<button id="bElim" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="rowElim(this);">' +
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" > </span>'+
    '</button>'+
    '<button id="bAcep" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display:none;" onclick="rowAcep(this);">' +
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" > </span>'+
    '</button>'+
    '<button id="bCanc" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="display:none;" onclick="rowCancel(this);">' +
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" > </span>'+
    '</button>'+
    '</div>';
var colEdicHtml = '<td name="buttons">'+newColHtml+'</td>';

$.fn.SetEditable = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
        columnsEd: null,         //Index to editable columns. If null all td editables. Ex.: "1,2,3,4,5"
        $addButton: null,        //Jquery object of "Add" button
        onEdit: function() {}   //Called after edition
        //onBeforeDelete: function() {}, //Called before deletion -- NOT USED
        //onDelete: function() {}, //Called after deletion -- NOT USED
        //onAdd: function() {}     //Called when added a new row -- NOT USED
    };
    params = $.extend(defaults, options);
    this.find('thead tr').append('<th name="buttons"></th>');  //encabezado vacío
    this.find('tbody tr').append(colEdicHtml);
    var $tabedi = this;   //Read reference to the current table, to resolve "this" here.
    //Process "addButton" parameter
    if (params.$addButton != null) {
        //Se proporcionó parámetro -- Parameter provided
        params.$addButton.click(function() {
            rowAddNew($tabedi.attr("id"));
        });
    }
    //Process "columnsEd" parameter
    if (params.columnsEd != null) {
        //Extract felds
        colsEdi = params.columnsEd.split(',');
    }
};
function IterarCamposEdit($cols, tarea) {
//Itera por los campos editables de una fila -- Go through the editable fields of a row
    var n = 0;
    $cols.each(function() {
        n++;
        if ($(this).attr('name')=='buttons') return;  //excluye columna de botones -- excludes button column
        if (!EsEditable(n-1)) return;   //noe s campo editable -- no editable field
        tarea($(this));
    });

    function EsEditable(idx) {
        //Indica si la columna pasada está configurada para ser editable -- Indicates if the last column is set to be editable
        if (colsEdi==null) {  //no se definió -- it was not defined
            return true;  //todas son editable -- all are editable
        } else {  //hay filtro de campos -- there is field filter
            for (var i = 0; i < colsEdi.length; i++) {
                if (idx == colsEdi[i]) return true;
            }
            return false;  //no se encontró -- it was not found
        }
    }
}
function FijModoNormal(but) {
    $(but).parent().find('#bAcep').hide();
    $(but).parent().find('#bCanc').hide();
    $(but).parent().find('#bEdit').show();
    $(but).parent().find('#bElim').show();
    var $row = $(but).parents('tr');  //accede a la fila -- access the row
    $row.attr('id', '');  //quita marca -- remove mark
}
function FijModoEdit(but) {
    $(but).parent().find('#bAcep').show();
    $(but).parent().find('#bCanc').show();
    $(but).parent().find('#bEdit').hide();
    $(but).parent().find('#bElim').hide();
    var $row = $(but).parents('tr');  //accede a la fila -- access the row
    $row.attr('id', 'editing');  //indica que está en edición -- indicates that it is in edicion
}
function ModoEdicion($row) {
    if ($row.attr('id')==='editing') {
        console.log('Entered Edit Mode'); //Added by CS
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('Exited Edit Mode'); //Added by CS
        return false;
    }
}
function rowAcep(but) {
    console.log('Called rowAcep function');
    //Acepta los cambios de la edición -- Accept the changes of the edition
    var $row = $(but).parents('tr');  //accede a la fila -- access the row
    var $cols = $row.find('td');  //lee campos -- read fields
    if (!ModoEdicion($row)) return;  //Ya está en edición -- Is already in edition
    //Está en edición. Hay que finalizar la edición -- It is in edition. You have to finish the edition
    IterarCamposEdit($cols, function($td) {  //itera por la columnas --iterate through the columns
        var cont = $td.find('input').val(); //lee contenido del input -- read input content
        $td.html(cont);  //fija contenido y elimina controles -- set content and remove controls
    });
    FijModoNormal(but);
    params.onEdit($row);
}
function rowCancel(but) {
//Rechaza los cambios de la edición -- Repeat the changes of the edition
    var $row = $(but).parents('tr');  //accede a la fila -- access the row
    var $cols = $row.find('td');  //lee campos read fields
    if (!ModoEdicion($row)) return;  //Ya está en edición -- It is already in edition
    //Está en edición. Hay que finalizar la edición -- It is in edition. You have to finalize the edition
    IterarCamposEdit($cols, function($td) {  //itera por la columnas -- iterate through the columns
        var cont = $td.find('div').html(); //lee contenido del div -- read div content
        $td.html(cont);  //fija contenido y elimina controles -- set content and remove controls
    });
    FijModoNormal(but);
}
function rowEdit(but) {  //Inicia la edición de una fila -- Start editing a row
    var $row = $(but).parents('tr');  //accede a la fila -- access the row
    var $cols = $row.find('td');  //lee campos -- read fields
    if (ModoEdicion($row)) return;  //Ya está en edición -- It is already in edition
    //Pone en modo de edición -- It puts in edit mode
    IterarCamposEdit($cols, function($td) {  //itera por la columnas -- iterate through the columns
        var cont = $td.html(); //lee contenido -- read content
        var div = '<div style="display: none;">' + cont + '</div>';  //guarda contenido -- keep content
        var input = '<input class="form-control input-sm"  value="' + cont + '">';
        $td.html(div + input);  //fija contenido -- set content
    });
    FijModoEdit(but);
}
```

I tried to access the button by selecting the `#bAcep` button that was **not** `style="display:none"`, but it still grabs the first one:

```
$('#bAcep').on('click', function () {
            console.log('Clicked bAcep button');
            //Get the <td> elements that are not the first or last (id and button)
            let text = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('td:gt(0):lt(6)');
            //Get the first button that is not display:none
            let visible_btn = $('#bAcep:not([style="display:none"]):first');
            //Get the id text in the first <td> element. To be used in the php script
            //let id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('td:eq(0)').text();
            let id = visible_btn.parent().parent().parent().find('td:eq(0)').text();
            //For debugging
            console.log('ID of row: ' + id);
            //Push the ID to the array to send to php
            array.push(id);
            //Push the rest to the array
            text.each(function () {
                array.push($(this).text());
            });
            //Open the confirm dialog
            $('#confirm_table_edit_dialog').dialog('open');
        });
```

My console output shows:

```
Clicked bAcep button
ID of row: 4
```

Here is a screenshot of the table:

[image: Table Screenshot]

Perhaps I'm missing something in the library?

Comment: Since this likely is NOT a PHP issue, please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve] WITHOUT PHP, including just enough relevant code to reproduce the issue

Comment: I am guessing `bAcep` is a duplicate ID. Use a class and navigate relatively to a parent - for example `let cells = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:gt(0):lt(6)');`

Comment: @mplungjan Removed PHP

Comment: @mplungjan The #bAcep id is genereated from the library. I can go into it and try to make it into a class instead.

Comment: If there is one per row, then it will only work with a class

Comment: @mplungjan Tried to change to a class in the bootstable.js code, but on click, it showed every single row in my console instead of just the first.

Comment: You will need to narrow it to the row it is on. As I said, post a relevant working example

Comment: @mplungjan Made a full working table without php

Comment: I made you the snippet I asked you for. I added jQuery UI but you also have some editable framework. Please add if needed or remove if not

Answer (score 0):

I took mplungjan's advice and utilized a class as an identifier for the button. I'm still using the click listener on the id, but find it by class within the function, like so:

First, in the library code, I hooked into the `rowAcep` function call and added a class, `accept`:

```
function rowAcep(but) {
    $(but).addClass('accept'); //<-- ADDED CLASS HERE
    //Acepta los cambios de la edición -- Accept the changes of the edition
    var $row = $(but).parents('tr');  //accede a la fila -- access the row
    var $cols = $row.find('td');  //lee campos -- read fields
    if (!ModoEdicion($row)) return;  //Ya está en edición -- Is already in edition
    //Está en edición. Hay que finalizar la edición -- It is in edition. You have to finish the edition
    IterarCamposEdit($cols, function($td) {  //itera por la columnas --iterate through the columns
        var cont = $td.find('input').val(); //lee contenido del input -- read input content
        $td.html(cont);  //fija contenido y elimina controles -- set content and remove controls
    });
    FijModoNormal(but);
    params.onEdit($row);
}
```

Then, my code:

```
//Click handler for edit accept button
$('#bAcep').on('click', function () {
    console.log('Clicked bAcep button');
    //Get the <td> elements that are not the first or last (id and button)
    let text = $('.accept').closest('tr').find('td:gt(0):lt(6)'); //<-- New Code Here

    //Get the id text in the first <td> element. To be used in the php script
    let id = $('.accept').closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text(); //<-- And here

    //Rest of code here
});
```

So, it was indeed an issue with a duplicate id. I guess poor design with the library, but it works now!

Comment: @mplungjan The plugin ties the click event into the rowAcep() function, which occurs when the "checkmark" button is clicked (the checkmark in the screenshot). So, the class doesn't exist until it's clicked. Doing the onClick by class resulted in the plugin taking over and returning to its default behavior.